# Hooking mute switch (Jailbroken)

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, cydia-substrate

I want to override the mute switch to create a new action whenever the switch is switched.
So what is the method that is fired when the switch is changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook this method in the SpringBoard

```
SBMediaController - (void)setRingerMuted:(char)
```

If you just want to observer the switch event then you can observe system-wide notification `com.apple.springboard.ringerstate` with darwin notification center like this

```
static void RingerStateChanged(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
}

CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                NULL,
                                RingerStateChanged,
                                CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.ringerstate"),
                                NULL,
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

Comment: I've searched a lot on how to listen to darwin notifications but almost didn't find anything. So could you please give me an example on that? :)

Comment: It's documented by Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I've already read that, but it's confusing. I want a real example for _ringerstate_ notification. also if I want to override the **setRingerMuted:** method, it accepts a char argument, so how to figure out if its on or off? I think it's bool not char. Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: BOOL is typedef for char, so yes, in this case it's a boolean argument.

Comment: so please, can you give me an example of the darwin notification observing?